# How do I resolve Non String values, when using a WebService to access SqlServer

Tags: sql-server, web-services, xaml, uwp, template10

I'm currently trying to build a UWP app that points to a SqlServer, and thru much research, determined that my best plan of attack was to create a WebService and make EF Calls to "CRUD" the dbase.

I found a good tutorial that helped a lot, however, I'm still new at this so seeing what some else did, and adapting is a learning experience. So it has caused a few questions to come up, that I have yet to solve.

These are my question;

1. HostName below is an INT in the Database and POGO Class.. So I'm getting the "cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string'" error. How do I resolve this? Do I use StringFormatConverter that is part of the Template I'm using?
2. The last value, EMV is a boolean value. It is currently pointing to a Toggleswitch and is pointing to the IsOn property of the Control. Will that resolve correctly?
3. Lastly, I would like to keep as much of my code adherent to the MVVM format. So If I move the below code below from Code Beyond to the ViewModel would that perform better?

Here is the Code Behind inside the Click Event...

```
private async void Save_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   var tblDevice = new Device { HostName = hostNameTB.Text, Server =serverIPTB.Text, RouterName = routerNameTB.Text, IP = iPTB.Text, Gateway =gatewayTB.Text, Hardware = hardwareTB.Text, EMV = eMVTB.IsOn};

   var deviceJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tblDevice);
   var client = new HttpClient();
   var HttpContent = new StringContent(deviceJson);
   HttpContent.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("Application/json");

   await client.PostAsync("http://localhost:2463/api/Devices", HttpContent);

   Frame.GoBack();
}
```

Here is the XAML

```
<TextBox Name="hostNameTB" />
<TextBox Name="serverIPTB" />
<TextBox Name="routerNameTB" />
<TextBox Name="iPTB" />
<TextBox Name="gatewayTB" />
<TextBox Name="hardwareTB" />
<ToogleSwitch Header="EMV" IsOn="False" Name="eMVTB" OffContent="UnConfigured" OnContent="Configured" />
```

Answer (score 0):

1 Int32.Parse(hostNameTB.Text) or via the Converter your choice.

2 Yes it will come thru as a 1 or a 0, true/false etc.  In the DB I assume this a 
BIT type?

3) it will perform the same only difference is testability